# Install Hibernate in Eclipse 3.6

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Can someone please explain how to install the hibernate plugin in Eclipse 3.6. I have tried to use the automatic install through market place but when after when i try to import the package 
import org.hibernate...
it does not sees the file

Please, I'm in a real mess, someone helps please

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is that you don't add the hibernate jar to the buildpath of your project, and not that the plug-in is misconfigured.

Comment: Can u tell me where to add this hibernate jar??